# Android interval timer with text to speech and variable-length named intervals

Tags: android, time-management, speech-synthesis

My third-grader has [trouble focusing on her homework](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/9033/178), and we've worked out a deal where she does active exercises for 10 minutes, works for 20 minutes, reads a book of her choice for 10 minutes, and back to the beginning. This seems to be going pretty well — two or three cycles of this and her homework is done.

I would like a timer which would could remember this sequence, and start it with a click. At the end of each period, a voice would say what to do next.  As a bonus, it would be nice to have a light chime or even a voice countdown. (My daughter also requests one-minute interval announcements during the exercise period.)

I found a whole lot of timer apps, many with text to speech, but the ones which do variable length steps don't seem to do the talking, and the vice versa. Text-to-speech is ideal but the ability to play back a recorded clip would be fine too.

I also need it to have no distracting ads — either pay to remove them or an add-free version, either way.

I found [Talk Interval Timer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ctrlb.talkinterval), which covers all of the bases, except it is completely unreliable, both crashing and doing things like playing all of the end-of-sequence announcements at once. (And the author is non-responsive.) What else could we use?